# iOS Date format 28 Mar 2016 / 16:54pm

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdateformatter

I want to display the date in the format "28 Mar 2016 / 16:54pm" from the string "2017-05-05T08:27:31.337Z". How can I do this? Is there any buildin method for iOS? Thanks.

Comment: Use `NSDateFormatter`

Comment: NSString <- Using NSDateFormatter -> NSDate. So Use a NSDateFormatter to read your String into a NSDate with the correct format, then transform that date into the target NSString with another dateFormat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `NSDateFormatter` for your concept

for e.g

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"];
NSDate *msgDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:@"2017-05-05T08:27:31.337Z"];
 [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd MMM yyyy / HH:mma"];
NSString *final = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:msgDate];
```

**update**

add `setAMSymbol` and `setPMSymbol` in your `dateFormatter`.

```
 [dateFormatter setAMSymbol:@"am"];
 [dateFormatter setPMSymbol:@"pm"];
```

**Full Answer**

```
 NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"];
NSDate *msgDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:@"2017-05-05T08:27:31.337Z"];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd MMM yyyy / HH:mma"];
[dateFormatter setAMSymbol:@"am"];
[dateFormatter setPMSymbol:@"pm"];
NSString *final = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:msgDate];
```

Comment: nirav see this `16:54pm`, the questioner need in `24 hour format`, thats why I used `/ HH:mma`

Comment: May be its typo mistake, why anyone want to show date in 24 hour with am and pm

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik when i applied `/ HH:mma` it's showing `/ 15:27PM`. So, how to do lowercase `PM`? I'm expecting that will show `/ 15:27pm`

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik Set it to again `HH` as of you are right and OP want 24 hour format.

Comment: @NiravD - its ok bro

Answer (score 0):

See Instruction or introduction with every line

```
NSString *str = @"your date here..."; /// here this is your date with format yyyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ

NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init]; // here we create NSDateFormatter object for change the Format of date..
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"]; //// here set format of date which is in your output date (means above str with format)

NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString: str]; // here you can fetch date from string with define format

dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd MMM yyyy / HH:mma"];// here set format which you want...

NSString *convertedString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date]; //here convert date in NSString
NSLog(@"Converted String : %@",convertedString);
```